# Messaging System with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

Hi I'm trying to make a messaging system with php and mysql.

The mysql table is simple:
id
sender
receiver
text
timestamp

I'm trying to make the messaging somewhat like Facebook/Twitter so the list is in 'conversations' and the **last message in the conversation** is viewed.

This is what I have atm:

```
(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver = 13 OR sender = 13 GROUP BY receiver,sender ORDER BY id ASC) ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: You can try by desc after group by keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT messages.* FROM messages, (SELECT MAX(id) as lastid FROM messages 
WHERE receiver = 13 OR sender = 13 
GROUP BY CONCAT(LEAST(receiver,sender),'.',GREATEST(receiver,sender))) as conversations
WHERE id = conversations.lastid
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

what you need is a unique conversation id between the chat-partners. i've simulated this with the subquery, hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!  This isn't my question, but I was looking for the same thing and this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Use `DESC` for fetch new rows, default is `ASC`

```
   (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver = 13 OR sender = 13 GROUP BY receiver,sender ORDER BY id DESC)
```

AND SET [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) 1 ,1 AFTER ORDER BY

I think you need to

`(receiver = '{receiver id}' AND sender = '{sender id}' ) OR (receiver ='{sender id}' AND sender = '{receiver id}' )`

Comment: This works but I can see a message I sent to someone else and the message they replied. I'm trying to make it one conversation with the last message sent between the 2 people displayed.

Comment: Put LIMIT 1,1 AFTER ORDER BY

Comment: Conversations I'm having with other people aren't displayed

Comment: Create Unique Session For Any chat And set for it `receiver ` And `sender`.But my answer is ok!

Comment: change `receiver = 13 OR sender = 13 ` to `receiver = 13 `

Comment: That works but I need to view the last message sent in the conversation. Is there anyway to retrieve the most bottom rows in SQL?

Comment: `(receiver = 13 AND sender = 'usersender id' ) OR (receiver ='usersender id' AND sender = 13 )` Try it!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDAte**:
I'm not sure if it works perfect:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE receiver = 13
GROUP BY receiver,sender 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1

UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE sender = 13
GROUP BY receiver,sender 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

to reverse the order:

```
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: The problem is I'm viewing multiple conversations. I need to just to view 1 per person and view the last message sent in the conversation.

Comment: you can use LIMIT 1 after ORDER

Comment: True but then I won't see conversations with other people.

Comment: can you explain more? because I dont get what you mean